# Display picture on Android app

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve a pic which is on a server. So i'm trying to retrieve it with th following method:

```
  static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
            return null;
        }

        final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                inputStream = entity.getContent(); 
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();  
                }
                entity.consumeContent();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
        getRequest.abort();
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then in another method i have the following two lines:

```
      ImageView e = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
      e.setImageBitmap(downloadBitmap(img_url(param1.img)));
```

And the xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Name Label -->
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/img"  
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:contentDescription="@string/picture">         
    </ImageView>
```

However the picture is not being displayed and i don't receive any error.
Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the url you are providing is correct? And that it actually does contain an image?

Comment: Hi Vishwa. Yes I'm 100% sure about the url and the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend to use the library ['Universal Image Loader'](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to display the image.

Comment: Universal Image Loader is always a good choice on Android. The code written above will start giving OutOfMemeory exceptions when loading large images or multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding a log statement to this catch statement:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
    getRequest.abort();
}
```

It's possible that it's throwing another exception in there that you're not aware of.